# Error in Accessing variable in EJS template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using the Ejs templating engine for my expressjs project and despite passing my objects along to my view chat.ejs file, I am receiving an undefined value in my ejs file.

routes.js:

```
async function redirectIfLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user){
    const user = await UserModel.findById(req.session.passport.user).exec(); 
    console.log(user.username);
    return res.render('chat.ejs', {user : user.username});
  } 
  return next();
}
```

chat.ejs :

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    .
    .
    .
    <script>
            alert(1);
            var username = <%= user %>;
            alert(2);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

1.Server: In terminal Prints username which is passed as variable to the template

2.Client: After page load it Gives only alert(1) not alert(2).And tried accessing username from clients console which gives undefined.

3. Even tried replacing  <%= user %> to  <%= locals.user %>

Answer (score 0):

Using `<%= %>` is for turning that expression into html "code". All you have to do is write `var username = user;` which is all javascript. An example of when you would use `<%= %>` is:

```html
<p>Username: <%= user %></p>
```

Comment: I did tried using ```var username =user``` but it was undefined.Just for surety tried again still it was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem intially i was curious about the datatype which is passed so i checked using `typeof()` and got undefined.Then i inspected the loaded page, if the value is assigned ; and yes the value got assigned.

P.s : I was using username as arg for `socket.emit('username',username)'`

So i tried converting the user template variable to string but wasnt successfull then
Finally After working tons of hours.This change of code worked fine:

`var username = <%= user %>;` changed to `var username = "<%= user %>";`